# Innovative way for checking if number has only one on bit in signed int

Tags: algorithm, byte

I'm looking for an innovative way to check if a number has only one on bit in a signed int.

I am well aware that I can simply do a loop with a counter, some modular division, and a bit shift. But I'm curious if there is a better way since we are only looking for ONE bit to be on.

```
bool HasOnlyOneBit (int  numb)
{
   //return true if numb has only one bit (I.E. is equal to 1, 2, 4, 8, 16... Int.MinValue)
}
```

Comment: Innovative?  You mean, something that uses genetic algorithms that cloud compute on quantum computers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if only one single bit is set within an integer (whatever its position)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420241/check-if-only-one-single-bit-is-set-within-an-integer-whatever-its-position)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
return x == (x & -x);
```

This answer works because of the way two's complement notation is designed.

First, an example. Assume we have 8-bit signed integers.

```
00010000  =  16
11110000  = -16
```

The bitwise and will give you `00010000` as a result, equal to your original value! The reason that this works is because when negating in 2's complement, first invert all the bits, then add 1. You'll have a bunch of zeros and a bunch of carries until a one falls into place. The bitwise and then checks if we have the right bit set.

In the case of a number that isn't a power of two:

```
  00101010  =  42
& 11010110  = -42
----------
  00000010 !=  42
```

Your result will still have only a single bit, but it won't match the original value. Therefore your original value had multiple bits set.

**Note:** This technique returns true for 0, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: You also need to test for `x > 0`, since this expression returns true for `x == 0`, but 0 is not a power of 2.

Comment: just be careful, this won't work for 0, you need to handle it by itself

Answer (score 25):

This is a famous problem

```
(x & x-1) == 0
```

Power of 2 from Wiki : [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two)

```
64 = 01000000 (x)
63 = 00111111 (x-1)
______________
&  = 00000000  == 0
______________
```

Case when some other bits are ON

```
18 = 00010010 (x)
17 = 00010001 (x-1)
______________
&  = 00010000  != 0
______________
```

Comment: take care of edge case where x!=0

Comment: sorry I meant when x=0 --> x & (x - 1) --> 0 , so instead of false it returns true!

Comment: The code is correct, but the explanation is wrong. 18 & 17 is 16, not 19 as you suggest.

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend you take a look at the [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) page and choose the most suitable option under "[Determining if an integer is a power of 2](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2)" or "[Counting bits set](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive)".

Answer (score 2):

`return (x && ((x & x-1) == 0))`

Answer (score 1):

```
return (x && (0x8000000000000000ULL % x));
```

This is a simplification of the following code:

```
if (x == 0) {
    return false;
} else if (0x8000000000000000ULL % x) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Explanation: 0x8000000000000000 is the highest "1 bit only" value for an 64 bit register. Only a division by an other "1 bit only" value will result in no remainder.

Answer (score 0):

Take the log to base 2 of your number, if it's an integer your number has only 1 1 bit.  Not sure that I think this is better than any of your excluded options.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 memory-efficient solution

```
return n > 0 and (n & (n-1)) == 0
```